# How to script the profiling of multiple executable on an Android device?

Tags: android, android-ndk, profiling, profiler

I have some executables that I compiled with the native toolchain, the NDK, for Android.

I would like to script the execution of this programs and since I'm interested in the performance of the application, I would like to run them to get the basic information about the execution like CPU usage, time, memory, and the usual stuff for a basic profiler.

It's possible to do this starting from the executables on my pc, pushing them to my device, run them and get back the information that I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

you could try these executables on linux using pss vss monitoring commands or even memusage command, but own't be effective unless its tried on android device. You could use DDMS for profiling android apps, you can do method profiling or trace profiling.

Have a look at: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: If I have 10 different versions of the same executable this will be a real pain. I was looking for something that I can script, with at least some basic information, just to make some choice between different way of compiling the same sources.

Comment: you could use some lib for NDK profiling using https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/ but real scenario would be on android right? So, the results might vary.